# Interfacing Subversion with git

Tags: svn, git, version-control

I do a lot of my coding on my school Mac, but I can't install any new programs on it due to school policy.  I've been using SVN for all my projects since it's pre-installed, but I would like to migrate to git.

Is there any way to use Subversion alongside git?  Can they somehow update/pull from the same server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn). Check out this guide: [Using Git with Subversion](http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Git as a Subversion client with the [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) set of commands. This works pretty well (within the limitations of Subversion).

Answer (score 1):

git-svn

It's part of the Git package and even has a help page included.  Read that first and then come back with any questions if you still have problems.